# How to get a google search service without using a div element?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I have this code:

```
<div id="map" style="display: none"></div>
```

js

```
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
    var pyrmont = {lat: -36.1699, lng: 115.1398};

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));

    infowindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch({
        location: pyrmont,
        radius  : 500,
        query   : 'Las Vegas Vehicle Inspection Stations'
    }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            console.log(results[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

To get the results i have to add the `map` to `var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);`

is there a way to get the results without using a `div` element?

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results without a **map** div.  You are required to provide either a [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlacesService) or an HTML Div (so attributions can be rendered):

> google.maps.places.PlacesService **Constructor**
>
> PlacesService(attrContainer:HTMLDivElement|Map)
>   Creates a new instance of the PlacesService that renders attributions in the specified container.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/60cm8ewg/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {
    lat: -36.1699,
    lng: 115.1398
  };
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("placeDiv"));
  service.textSearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    query: 'Las Vegas Vehicle Inspection Stations'
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var resultsStr = "<table><tr><th>name</th><th>coordinates</th></tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      resultsStr += "<tr><td>" + results[i].name + "</td><td>" + results[i].geometry.location.toUrlValue(6) + "</td></tr>";
      console.log(results[i]);
    }
    resultsStr += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = resultsStr;
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="placeDiv"></div>
<div id="results"></div>
```